# Android EditText file format

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I have edit text in my app, that captures only decimal numbers.
I've set an input type to DECIMAL_NUMBERS.

The problem is, what if user puts for example 0009
I want to prevent that, and remove zeros on beginning.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. Tnx. :)

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (start == 0 && s.toString().equals("0"))
                editText.setText("");
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Override `onTextChanged (CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)` method to correct user input and add it using `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: tell him to add `addTextChangedListener` on `Edittext` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the zeros via a `regex` and `replaceFirst` function of string `replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")`

You can try the regex here: http://regexr.com?32f1o